# Eigen: Computing norms of matrix rowwise, is slower than computing them iteratively on vectors

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to accelerate a computation of vector norms using Eigen.

Tried doing it in two ways:

### Way 1: Storing the vectors separately in an array (std::vector)

```
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, VECTOR_SIZE>> my_vectors(num_vectors);
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> norms(num_vectors, 1);
for (int i = 0 ; i < my_vectors.size() ; i++) {
    norms(i, 0) = my_vectors[i].norm();
}
```

### Way 2: Storing the vectors as rows of the same matrix and using rowwise norm

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, VECTOR_SIZE> my_vectors(num_vectors, VECTOR_SIZE);
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> norms = my_vectors.rowwise().norm();
```

I was surprised to see that whereas **Way1** is slow, **Way2** is even slower.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to compute the norms faster?

In another test I made, the same was true for vector subtraction. An iteration over separate vectors, reducing the same vector from each, was faster than storing all the vectors as matrix rows and using `.rowwise() - vector_to_subtract`

Comment: Which Eigen version, which compiler, what compile flags are you using? And how big is `num_vectors` typically, and do you initialize the memory of `my_vectors`?

Answer (score 2):

From https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html

> If the storage order is not specified, then Eigen defaults to storing the entry in column-major. This is also the case if one of the convenience typedefs (Matrix3f, ArrayXXd, etc.) is used.

My best guess is memory access issues: `rowwise()` is probably doing a bunch of "skipping" in memory, i.e. not reading consecutive regions - while storing each row separately does not suffer from this problem.

**WARNING:** While I wrote my answer with best of intentions, I couldn't test it myself, and apparently it would slow things down even further. Thanks [SomethingSomething](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3322273/somethingsomething) for testing the idea.

Comment: So I am changing the matrix definition from `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, VECTOR_SIZE>` to `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, VECTOR_SIZE, Eigen::RowMajor>`. When I can check the performances again, I will tell you whether it really solved the problem

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately.. Even became slower... I finally remained with my `std::vector` workaround and succeeded accelerating my flow using multithreading (The speed problem was there when I needed to make a lot of such row-wise computations. Dividing them to up to 16 threads did the work)